# Finding the side lengths of a 45 degree triangle with shared hypotenuse.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, graphing-functions

Right triangle A with hypotenuse 1 and sides x and y is graphed at the origin. Right triangle B is graphed so that it shares a hypotenuse with triangle A and it's sides w and z are parallel to the functions y = x and y = -x. Find w and z with respect to x and y.

[A link to a visual of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujacp.png)

In the configuration of the visual, I've been able to figure out that z = cos(135 - arctan(y/x)) * sqrt(x^2 + y^2) and w = cos(45 - arctan(x/y) * sqrt(x^2 + y^2). HOWEVER, in another configuration where say, x is larger than y, or ANY of the coordinates were negative, this would not work.

I need a formula to find w and z that works 100% of the time.

Any and all help solving this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Writing this as a comment, instead of an answer, because it is much more convenient to me to keep my response informal.  The reason that you are having trouble with the general case is that you have taken what I regard as the wrong approach.  Instead of trying to come up with a universal formula, you should come up with a universal procedure.  In the diagram,  the problem is defeated by determining the Cartesian coordinates of point $w$, which represents the intersection of two lines: $y = -x$, and the line of slope $(1)$ that passes through $(x,y)$.  ...see next comment

Comment: Once point $w$ is identified, then it should be straightforward to create an algorithm that solves the problem based on point $w$.  So, in the variety of cases, you always need to create two algorithms: one that identifies a specific point of intersection, and the other that uses this identification to complete the problem.  So, all that you have to do, is take out scratch paper, write down all of the special cases to examine, and then explore each one, one at a time. ...see next comment

Comment: With each special case, you will want a step 1 to identify the pertinent point of intersection, and then step 2 to complete the problem.  Then, after all of this is done, if you need to create a universal formula (e.g. if you are putting this into a computer program), then you will simply have to structure the functions that identify the intersection point and then complete the problem so that they accept a wide variety of inputs.

Comment: This is an interesting way of looking at this problem. I will try this, thank you.

Comment: The perimeter defines a inscribable quadrilateral so you have formulas applying rightforwardly

Answer (score 1):

We can start by labelling some angles in your picture.

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6y6j.png`

Assume that every angle that is on there is exactly like the picture you sent. This means that $\angle BAC = \sin^{-1} \left( y \right)$. Since the side length $w$ is on $y = -x$, it means that $\angle DAC = 135^{\circ}$. This means that $\angle DAB = 135^\circ - \sin^{-1} \left( y \right)$ Now we can use law of sines: $$\frac{1}{\sin 90^\circ} = \frac{z}{\sin \left(135^\circ - \sin^{-1} \left( y \right) \right)}$$ This means that $z = \sin \left( 135^\circ - \sin^{-1} \left( y \right) \right)$

Since we have two of the three angles in $\triangle DAB$ we know that $\angle DBA = 180 - \left(90 + \left(135 - \sin^{-1} \left( y \right) \right) \right) = 90 - \left( 135 - \sin^{-1} \left( y \right) \right)$. We repeat law of sines: $$\frac{1}{\sin 90^\circ} = \frac{w}{\sin \left(\angle DBA \right)} = \frac{w}{\sin \left( 90 - \left( 135 - \sin^{-1} \left( y \right) \right) \right)}$$ This means that $w = \sin \left(-45 - \sin^{-1}\left(y \right) \right)$.